# ajax is producing [object object]?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm getting an [object object] from my ajax response.

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            data: "id_1="+id_1+"&id_2="+id_2,
            url:"ajax/url.php"
        }).done(function(data){
            var left= $(data).find("#left");
        $("#left").html(left);
            alert(left);


        });
```

In my url, I just have a simple coding

```
if(isset($_GET["id_1"]) && isset($_GET['id_2'])){
    $id_1 = $_GET["id_1"];
    $id_2 = $_GET['id_2'];

    $right= $dbh->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE id_1 = ?");
    $right->execute(array($id_1));
    $left= $dbh->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE id_1 = ? ");
    $left->execute(array($id_2));


    <div id='right'><?php echo $right->fetchColumn();?></div>

    <div id='left'><?php echo $left->fetchColumn();?></div>



}
```

When I this is all done, it alerts back [object object]

anyone know why it does that?

Thanks!

EDIT:

I added some coding in the .done(function())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Have solved my problem. The issue was that I needed to wrap my div's within another . After that the find() method would be able to capture those id's and return the proper objects.

```
if(isset($_GET["id_1"]) && isset($_GET['id_2'])){
    $id_1 = $_GET["id_1"];
    $id_2 = $_GET['id_2'];

    $right= $dbh->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE id_1 = ?");
    $right->execute(array($id_1));
    $left= $dbh->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE id_1 = ? ");
    $left->execute(array($id_2));

<div> // wrapper
    <div id='right'><?php echo $right->fetchColumn();?></div>

    <div id='left'><?php echo $left->fetchColumn();?></div>
</div>



}
```

Answer (score 11):

`data` is an object. `[object Object]` is just the object's `toString()` response.

You need to access the object's data. Try using `console.log(data)` to check its contents.

It looks like from your PHP example that you have not provided the code *as is*. The code you posted will be a syntax error.

Also, check the MIME type of your response. You may want to force the `dataType` as `html`.

Comment: Everyone should be forced to read [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) before posting a question on SO

Comment: make sure to strip your code of all `console.log()` before you publish though because IE gets stuck on it.  I've spent hours debugging only to find I left a `console.log()` hanging out in my code...

Comment: @JoshV.K. Or implement your own `console.log()` :)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I get html code when I use alert(data), but when I'm finding something, it gets the object issue

Comment: it will return `[object object]` when you receive back multiple elements in an object.

Comment: also, how would I go about implementing my own `console.log()`?

Comment: @JoshV.K. *Quick-and-dirty* `console = console || { log: function(msg) { alert(msg); } }`. It's a very basic implementation and doesn't support 1% of the features but the idea is there :)

Comment: I'm trying to find an id though, shouldn't it just be simple as what code I have?

Comment: If I alert(left) I get the object message.

Comment: @andrewliu What does the raw response look like?

Comment: andrew, have you not tried console.log yet? it will give you an array of objects which you can use to reference any of the objects.  Just try `console.log(left);`. What does it pop out?

Comment: @JoshV.K. If I'm doing the console.log correctly (Using firebug right?) and it has like GET ajax/url.php?id.... all that stuff right? Well if do console.log(data) I get the correct data with the divs (both left and right). then when I just do console.log(left), I get `[ ]`

Comment: I have very limited use with firebug as I usually just use the Google Chrome Developer Tools.  I would guess that your `.find` function is returning `null` and therefore left.  Could you post a sample of the HTML output that you are returning? In both firebug and Chrome you can view what you are receiving back from the AJAX call in the network (net in firebug) tab.  Ensure that you are receiving back both `#left` and `#right`.

Comment: `<div id='right'>3</div>
<div id='left'>4</div>`

This is html i'm getting out

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an object back, and not a simple string... It looks like "data" would contain the response from your page "url.php"
What are you trying to do with "data" in your real app? I am assuming the alert is just a debug measure?

Comment: Hook up a JS debugger (in a browser) to see what you have to work with here :-)

Answer (score 0):

Where are you creating your JSON response? I assume it's the fetchColumn() method. Double-check to make sure that you're preparing with json_encode() properly...

What do you get when you dump everything?

```
var_dump( $right );
var_dump( $down );
var_dump( $right->fetchColumn() );
var_dump( $down->fetchColumn() );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try ..

```
$response = "";
$response .="<div id='right'>".$right->fetchColumn()."</div>";
$response .="<div id='down'>".$down->fetchColumn()."</div>";

echo $response;exit;
```