# Ajax call and returning json?

Tags: javascript, ajax

If my ajax call is returning:

```
[object,object]
```

Does it mean that the data is already in a json format?

What should it look like for a json encoded string?

Comment: Possible duplicat http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900910/ajax-is-producing-object-object

Comment: Returning it to what? It sounds like you attempted to display that value, rather than use a property of it. `console.log(data)` should show you the contents of the object. Perhaps you intend to display those. Please check the console.log and update your question.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON
and to try to log your call result to the console (console.log(var)) so you can have a better view of the real form in which data is passed.